# Upgrade magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to upgrade magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1 with composer 2, but I'm stuck with is error:

```
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires allure-framework/allure-phpunit ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.4].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 requires magento/framework 103.0.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.3-p1].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p1].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.8.0].
    - magento/framework[103.0.3, ..., 103.0.3-p1] require symfony/console ~4.4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.37].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/console[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.37, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.3, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3].
    - Conclusion: install symfony/console v2.8.38 (conflict analysis result)
```

Any help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer //set developer mode

php bin/magento -d memory_limit=6G maintenance:enable

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update

composer update or upload composer.phar in root and run php -d memory_limit=6G composer.phar update

rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

php bin/magento --version

php bin/magento maintenance:disable

Php version set 7.4 via cpanel or htaccess
```

Hope It will help !!

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this post, I found a solution and it was so simple that it makes feel dumb! I just tried to migrate version by version (24.2 ->2.4.2-p1 -> p2 and then 2.4.3.

Comment: ok Great  !!!!